# Angular2 W3C validation error for providing formControlName attribute

Tags: angular, w3c

In one of the Angular2 Application I have used a formControlName attribute in an input field with formgroup the the form.

Example :
`input formControlName="Searchbycombo"
class="customcombocontrol" type="text" name="Searchbycombo" id="ctry"`

But when I try to validate the page, W3c validator providing some error

> "Attribute formcontrolname not allowed on element input at this
>   point."

I have already gone through this url but no luck https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings

any idea how to fix the same.

Comment: Apparently that's not an officially-valid attribute of `input` elements.

Comment: List of valid input attributes: https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-input-element

Comment: Where's your `code`?

Comment: Sorry it was not displayed before I have added that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi Today I have received a reply form Angular team and they mentioned to use the below way

[formControlName]="'Searchbycombo'"

and its no longer giving any error on w3c validator after render.

Thanks all for the support and help